# Can I change grout color shortly after applying?

Tags: grout

I started grouting my backsplash, and an hour or so in, I realize I don't like the white grout. Can I use something and scrape out as much grout as possible, at least, and start over with a darker color? It's a polyblend unsanded grout if that matters!

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Scrape out as much as you can (gently, so as to not chip your tile's glazing), then use something damp to wipe away the original color from the surface so it doesn't show through or around the new color. You could even spray it away with water and maybe use a wet vac to catch runoff. Let any excess moisture dry up before proceeding, though.

Alternatively, look into grout stains. That may be simpler at this point.

Comment: thanks so much, I did get most of it out! Now I can start over with the grout!

Comment: You're welcome. Did you take the [tour]? "Thanks" comments are discouraged here.